# Using D3 with MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, mean-stack

I am new to *MEAN* (all web technologies) and *D3*. I am trying to include *D3, dc.js* to my application.

I added all the js files in **config/all.js**, nvd3 has angular module and added that in **public/config.js**. My question is how to make D3 available inside my controller?

With the help of [this link](https://blog.logentries.com/2014/07/combine-d3-with-angularjs/), I was able to include D3 as follows

```
     //Load D3 into the application
    var scriptTag = $document[0].createElement('script');
    scriptTag.src = 'http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js';
    scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 'complete') onScriptLoad();
    }
    scriptTag.onload = onScriptLoad;
    var s = $document[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    s.appendChild(scriptTag);
```

Since nvd3 references 'd3', I did the samething for nvd3 but the angular-nvd3 directive is complaining about 'nv' which is defined in nvd3.js file.

Could anyone let me know 
1. how to include 3rd party libraries 
2. Is there a way to defer the dependant(in my case angular-nvd3) till the dependency is loaded ('nvd3.js')
Thanks

Comment: Why are you making the inclusion of an external library so complicated? Why not just include a basic `script` tag into your `index.html` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include any d3 calls inside your controller, instead you can reference it inside a directive and include the reference of d3 in your app.all configuration file.

Or load the library by using a service and return a singleton and use it inside a directive, take a look to this [post](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html) is very useful and it describes how to use d3 and angular.

you can go either way, but be careful and don't mix the approaches.

Comment: Thank you. if I understood it correctly, with the approach 1, the d3 calls will be in html. I was referring to [this example](https://github.com/TomNeyland/angular-dc/blob/master/example/stocks/stock.js) where d3 calls were inside the controller. Will try this approach and please allow me a day to update.

Comment: option 1 the d3.js library will be referenced from the index.html as a regular script and you can reference from a directive (or in your case a controller)

Comment: This did not work for me when used from within the controller. I was getting d3 not defined (I copy pasted the code into my controller). I can share the code, if required. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using meanjs and I just wrote a reference like assets: {lib: js :[{'public/lib/d3/d3.js'}]

Comment: update the question with the relevant code if you want.

Comment: Thank you. I tried from scratch and this time, I was able to use d3 within controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66726/discussion-between-patb23-and-jack-the-ripper).